# When does conditional expectation equal expectation?

Tags: probability

Can someone explain when conditional expectation equals expectation

For example $X_n$ iid with $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\mathcal{F}_n^x$ is the natural filtration of $X$

$$E(X_n)=E(X_n|\mathcal{F}^X_{n-1})=0$$

Can someone give a calculation particularly about this example or when they're equal in general

Comment: Your example is incompletem. You don't say what $\mathcal{F}_{n-1} $ is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what do you think I am asking? @Did

Comment: What you ask is rather mysterious since the property in the question is usually dealt with in the very first lines of any notes on the subject (see the answer below if you need a confirmation, which basically says "This is a property of conditional expectations", rightfully so). What is your source on conditional expectation? (For future use, please note that stalling queries about your question like you just did, can be seen as a delaying tactics, not very constructive, hence your future reactions of the same ilk will not be answered.)

Comment: @Did what's stalling queries

Comment: Asking endlessly for explanations on minor points instead of making your question acceptable (this last comment of yours being a good example).

Comment: @Did idk what information you still need. How many version of conditional expectation do you know? If there are only a few, why need to list them? Even there are a few, are they inconsistent with this problem? There isn't anything mysterious and the answer below is what I wanted

Comment: Yes you received an answer to a question you asked with no context. Congrats. And the answer basically says: "Check the definition"... That should tell you something about your question. If you continue to pretend it does not, too bad.

Comment: definition $Y=E(X|\mathcal{F})$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable and $E(Y\mathbb{1}_D)=E(X\mathbb{1}_D)$ for all $D\in\mathcal{F}$. I don't see this relates to this question.

Comment: @ZHU To see the relation: If $X$ is independent from $\mathcal F$, then you can write $E[X1_D]=E[X]*E[1_D]=E[X]$ which is the desired property. BTW. you should mark your question as answered if you accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the filtration is the generated Filtration by $X_n$. As your $X_n$ are independent, $X_n$ is therefore independent from $\mathscr F_{n-1}^X$. The conditional expectation is equal to expectation if $X$ is independent from the sigma algebra, which is conditioned on.